# Spark/Spring validation-api dependencies conflict

Tags: spring, apache-spark, hadoop, dependencies

I run Spring/Spark app and face this problem

The following method did not exist:

```
javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration.getClockProviderClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
```

The method's class, `javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration`, is available from the following locations:

```
***validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar!/javax/validation/BootstrapConfiguration.class

***/BOOT-INF/lib/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar!/javax/validation/BootstrapConfiguration.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/spark2/jars/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

How do I make spark read my dependency first and then look at the system lib?

I tried to specify in Oozie

I tried to specify in spark-submit

Nothing worked so far.

Comment: I'm using spark-submit btw

Answer (score 1):

Had encountered a similar situation. I finally ended up doing as below. ie i copied the required jars to a directory, and used the extraClasspath option

```
spark-submit   --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath="C:\sparkjars\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\sparkjars\gson-2.8.6.jar" myspringbootapp.jar
```

From the documentaion, spark.driver.extraClassPath  Extra classpath entries ***to prepend to the classpath*** of the driver.

Comment: Please, how do you build you app ? Using spring boot maven plugin or the shade plugin ?

Comment: I use Spring Boot Maven plugin